# $\sigma$-algebra generated by open sets

Tags: measure-theory

I am starting my studies at measure theory, and I've seen the exercise below. I it not clear to me what I should do. I mean, is it to take a subset $A \in \mathcal{C}$ and show it is in $\mathcal{B}$? I am a bit confused. Could anyone give me a hand?

> Let $X=(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R}$, with its usual topology. Define $\mathcal{B}$ as the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets of $X$. Show that $\mathcal{C}:=\{[a,b] \mid a\leq  b, a,b \in X\}$ generates $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: You should show that the smallest sigma algebra that contains $\mathcal{C}$ is equal to the smallest sigma algebra that contains the open sets of $X$.

Comment: You want to show that each element of $\mathcal C$ is in $\mathcal B$ and you also want to show that each open set of $X$ is in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal C$, which you should prove you can do by showing that the open intervals of $X$ are in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal C$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $O$ denote the collection of open subsets of $X$. For any $S \subset P(X)$, let $\sigma(S)$ denote the smallest sigma algebra containing $S$, also known as the sigma-algebra generated by $S$. You want to show that $\sigma(O) = \sigma(C)$. To show $\sigma(O) \subset \sigma(C)$, it is sufficient to show that $O \subset \sigma(C)$ because $\sigma$ is monotonic and idempotent, that is, $S_1 \subset S_2 \implies \sigma(S_1) \subset \sigma(S_2)$ and $\sigma(\sigma(S)) = \sigma(S)$. Similarly, to show $\sigma(C) \subset \sigma(O)$, it is sufficient to show $C \subset \sigma(O)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $O$ be the set of all open subsets of $X.$ Let $s(O)$ be the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ generated by $O.$ Let $s(\mathcal C)$ be the $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ generated by $\mathcal C.$

The set $C_Q=\{[a,b]\in\mathcal C: a,b\in \Bbb Q\}$ is a countable subset of $\mathcal C.$

If $U\in O$ then $ \{c\in C_Q: c\subset U\}$ is a countable subset of $\mathcal C$ and $U=\bigcup \{c\in C_Q: c\subset U\}$ so $U\in s(\mathcal C).$ So $O\subset s(\mathcal C).$ So $$s(O)\subset s(\mathcal C).$$

If $V\in \mathcal C$ then $X\setminus V\in O$ so $X\setminus V\in s(O)$ so $V\in s(O).$ So $\mathcal C\subset s(O).$ So $$s(\mathcal C)\subset s(O).$$

Comment: Every open subset of $\Bbb R$ is the union of a countable family of closed sets. In topology this property is called "perfectly normal". In $\Bbb R$ we have more: An open set is the union of a countable family of closed bounded intervals. ("Countable" means "finite or countably infinite".) Another important property is that a bounded open subset of $\Bbb R$ is the union of a countable family of pairwise-disjoint open intervals.